# How to pass an image value from one form to another form?

Tags: php, forms, echo

i have an image at promotions.php . When i clicked on 'edit' link, the variables like 'title', 'description' and 'image' would be passed on to doEditPromotion.php's page form.

I can pass 'title' and 'description' to be displayed on doEditPromotion.php's page form but not the image value.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

doEditPromotion.php -->

```
<?php
  session_start();
  include "dbfunction.php";

  $id = $_REQUEST['id'];


 $query = "SELECT title, description, image, promotionID FROM promotion WHERE promotionID = '$id'";

  $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


        $title = $row['title'];
        $description = $row['description'];
        $image = $row['image'];


// check if the form has been submitted. If it has, process the form and save it to the database

    if (isset($_POST['save']))
    {
        $title_save = $_POST['title'];
        $description_save = $_POST['description'];
        $target = 'images/';
        $target = $target.basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);
        $pic = ($_FILES['photo']['name']);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target);

// check that firstname/lastname fields are both filled in
 if ($title_save == '' || $description_save == '' || $pic == '')
 {
 // generate error message
 $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
 echo $error;
 }

    else
 {  
  // save the data to the database
  $query = "UPDATE promotion SET title = '$title_save', description = '$description_save', image = '$pic' WHERE promotionID = '$id'"; 
  $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

  // once saved, redirect back to the view page
 header("Location: promotions.php"); 
 }   
 }
          ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="codes.css"/>
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="picture-zoom/css/dg-picture-zoom.css" type="text/css" /> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="picture-zoom/js/external/mootools-1.2.4-core-yc.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="picture-zoom/js/external/mootools-more.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="picture-zoom/js/dg-picture-zoom.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="picture-zoom/js/dg-picture-zoom-autoload.js"></script> 

        <script>
        function myFunction()
        {
        alert("Are you sure you want to proceed?");
        }
        </script>

    <title>Eco Canteen - Promotions</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrap">   
           <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">

               <br/>
                    <?php
                            if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
                            {
                            ?>
                        <p align="right"><a href="logout.php"><font color="white">Logout</font></a></p>
                        <?php
                            }
                            else
                            {
                        ?>

                        <form align="right" name="form" action="doIndex.php" method="post">
                        <p><label for="username"><font color="white"> Username: </font></label>
                        <input name="username" type="text"></input>

                        <label for="password"><font color="white"> Password: </font></label>
                        <input name="password" type="password"></input>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <input name="submit" value="Login" type="submit"/></p>
                    <?php
                                }
                    ?>
                        </form>

                </div>


<div id='menu'>

<ul>
   <li><a href='index.php'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='promotions.php'><span>Promotions</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='outlets.php'><span>Outlets</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='feedback.php'><span>Feedback</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Career</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='stall.php'><span>Stall Leasing</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='career.php'><span>Career Opportunity</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='contactUs.php'><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
</ul>

                </div>
                </div>



    <br/>     
    <br/>


    <p class="slogan"></p>

        <div id="intro">
        <h2><b>ECO CANTEEN</b></h2>

    </div>



<br/>

        <div class="wid_center">

        <div id="content">
        <div class="gao">
        <h3><a href="promotions.php">Promotion</a> > <b>Edit Promotion</b></h3>

        <fieldset stype='width:500px'>
        <legend><b>Promotion Details</b></legend>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>Promotion Title:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="title" size='36' value="<?php echo $title;?>"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Description:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="description" style='width: 300px;height:80px' value="<?php echo $description;?>"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Image:</td>
        <td><input type='file' name='upfile' id='image' src='images/<?php echo $_REQUEST['$image']?>'></input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="save" value="Save"/></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
        </fieldset>


        </div>

    <br/>
    <br/>



    <hr class="clear" />
    </div>
                </div>




    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>



    <div id="footer">
    <p> <br />
    Copyright &copy; 2012 EcoCanteen<br />
            </p></div>



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is your row[image] value are you showing this value in text field or <img> tag (if img tag then give your row[image] value with full path) your fetching query run before saving image

Answer (score 0):

You named the uploaded file upfile, and then tried to access it as photo. Do `print_r($_FILES)` and then change one of the following:

```
$_FILES['photo']['name'] // Either change photo to upfile
...
<input type='file' name='upfile' id='image' src='...' /> // Or upfile to photo
```